# What is 'ls quote'?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

Today I happened to press `'` after `ls`
So the command is `ls'`

```
> ls'
quote> ls'
zsh: command not found: ls\nls
>
```

Can someone tell me, what is the `ls quote` thing?

Comment: In the future, it's helpful to only screenshot the relevant portions. As it is, the text can't be read without opening the image in a new window and zooming in.

Comment: @Patrick Sure, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you opened a quotation `'` and pressed enter, the shell is wanting you to close the quote. The `quote>` prompt is simply a visual indication of such.

This is so that you can pass multi-line arguments to programs.

For example:

```
$ echo 'hi
quote> there'

hi
there
```

Since you typed <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, this is the equivalent to trying to run a command called `ls\nls` (a command with a newline character in the middle of it), which doesn't exist and so the shell gave you an error.

Answer (score 2):

That `quote>`  is the `$PS2` (aka `$PROMPT2` in `zsh`) prompt, the secondary prompt string.

The primary prompt string (`$PS1` / `$PROMPT`), `>`  it seems in your case, is the one that invites you to enter a command. The secondary command is the one that invites you to continue and finish your command.

It's displayed after you've pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the command was not finished yet.

In `zsh`, the default value of `$PS2` is `%_>` , where `%_` is (documented under [Prompt Expansion / Shell State](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state)):

> %_
>
> The status of the parser, i.e. the shell constructs (like `if` and `for`) that have been started on the command line. If given an integer number that many strings will be printed; zero or negative or no integer means print as many as there are. This is most useful in prompts `PS2` for continuation lines and `PS4` for debugging with the `XTRACE` option; in the latter case it will also work non-interactively.

For instance, if I enter:

```
my-PS1-prompt> (while true; do for i in "${var-qwe
subsh while for dquote braceparam>
```

The shell tells me I still need to close that `${...}` brace parameter expansion, the `"..."` double quote, finish the `for` and `while` statement and close the subshell before that command is complete and shell can start running it.

In your case, it tells you you need to close that `'...'` single-quoted string. Once you do, it tries to run the corresponding command and fails as there's no `ls<newline>ls` command on your system.

Note that instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you could have pressed <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which on some terminals you  can also enter as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for a literal newline character (aka `^J`) to be entered in the editing buffer instead of the current line to be submitted to the shell. In that case, you won't see the secondary  prompt, and you'll be able to move the cursor back to the first line.

Beside `$PS1` and `$PS2`, there's also `$PS3` (aka `$PROMPT3`), used in `select` statements,  `$PS4` (aka `$PROMPT4`) used for `xtrace` debugging output, `$RPS1` (`$RPROMP`) and `$RPS2` (`$RPOMPT2`) like `$PS1`/`$PS2` except they are printed on the  right side of the screen.

`$PS1,2,3,4` are from the Korn shell, while `%x` special sequences are from `csh` (greatly expanded by `zsh`).  [POSIX specifies all but `PS3`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) (as it doesn't specify `ksh`'s `select` statement), but not the `%x` sequences.

`tcsh` had `$prompt` and `$rprompt` which inspired `zsh`'s `$RPS1` / `$PRS2`.

The `bash` shell chose a different (and unfortunate) syntax for its special sequences in its `$PSx` prompts using `\` instead of `%` and different and incompatible letters from the ones in `tcsh`/`zsh`. `%_` is `zsh`-specific.

Comment: What is a braceparam?